# Drawing a line within boundaries from point (x, y) with a given angle

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, trigonometry, angle

I am trying to draw a line on JavaScript canvas. I have two points A and B (as shown in the picture).

[image: Points A and B]

I use this code to find the angle between these two points:

```
// p1 is point A and p2 is point B    
var theta = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
```

Now I want to draw a line from point A till the end of the canvas and I also want to get the point where the line ends (point C in the picture).

[image]

Can this be achieved using the angle and size(width & height) of the canvas?

Comment: I think this is not about programming, this is basic mathematics.

Comment: tell me the solution either way, programatically or mathematically :)

Comment: Close. But you do not need to calculate the angle, you only need to calculate the slope. Then use the slope against the point in the edge of the canvas (either the height or the width)

Comment: omg that sounds solid. trying it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to solve this problem without trigonometric functions. At first construct parametric representation of given AB ray:

```
 x = A.X + dx * t
 y = A.Y + dy * t
   where
 dx = B.X - A.X
 dy = B.Y - A.Y
```

The check what edge will be intersected first (with smaller t value):

```
//potential border positions    
if dx > 0 then
   ex = width
else
   ex = 0

if dy > 0 then
   ey = height
else
   ey = 0

//check for horizontal/vertical lines 
if dx = 0 then
    return cx = A.X,  cy = ey

if dy = 0 then
    return cy = A.Y,  cx = ex


//in general case find parameters of intersection with horizontal and vertical edge
tx = (ex - A.X) / dx
ty = (ey - A.Y) / dy

//and get intersection for smaller parameter value
if tx <= ty then
   cx = ex
   cy = A.Y + tx * dy
else
   cy = ey
   cx = A.X + ty * dx

return cx, cy
```

Results for Width = 400, Height = 300, fixed A point and various B points:

```
100:100 - 150:100   400: 100
100:100 - 150:150   300: 300
100:100 - 100:150   100: 300
100:100 - 50:150     0: 200
100:100 - 50:100     0: 100
100:100 - 50:50     0:   0
100:100 - 100:50   100:   0
100:100 - 150:50   200:   0
```

Comment: what is `t` here?

Comment: This is auxiliary parameter used in calculations but not in result. It defines position of points at AB ray. At point A t=0, at B t=1

Comment: this is not working, the angle is correct but the length of the line is too long. The x and y in first two lines of your code were never used?

Comment: [My Code](https://imgur.com/a/fGTlu) and my [Result](https://imgur.com/a/JmjaG). In case 1 & 2 when A's Y coordinate is less than B's Y coordinate, the angle is correct but the line goes out of canvas. In case 3 & 4 there is no line.

Comment: Just checked - typo was in (dx>0) condition, but your code is corrected here. After correction code works well. What is `canvas.y` in your code? And return values are exchanged in `dy==0`  case

Comment: sorry man its working perfectly, my variable was `canvas_dimensions` not `canvas`. :'''')

Answer (score 0):

your example calculates the polar angle (not the angle between two Points - that's impossible). To calculate where the Extended line touches the canvas calculate the Y-difference (dY) between P1 and the bottom of the canvas, use the atan of the angle to calculate dX. If P1.x + dX is smaller than your canvas width, the line hits the bottom at cut.X = P1.x + dX. If it is bigger, it hits the right side. To get the Y value where it hits, think of a small triangle formed by the part of the right side of canvas below the Point where the Extended line cuts the right side and the Point where the line will cut the (horizontal Extended) bottom of the canvas. The Y part is cut.X -canvas.width * atan(90-angle).

Probably you have to determine, in which direction the extended line is Extended.

More simpler solution:
Since JavaScript draw clips at canvas border by itself, you could extend your line very long (i.e. by size of canvas diagonal length) and you are done.

Comment: you mean something like this? [link](https://imgur.com/a/eeqUJ)