# Fill in shape with lines at a specified angle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry

I need to create line segments within a shape and not just a visual pattern - I need to know start and end coordinates for those lines that are within a given boundary (shape). I'll go through what I have and explain the issues I'm facing

I have a **closed** irregular shape (can have dozens of sides) defined by `[x, y]` coordinates

```
shape = [
  [150,10], // x, y
  [10,300],  
  [150,200],
  [300,300]
];
```

I calculate and draw the bounding box of this shape

[image]

I then draw my shape on the canvas

[image]

Next, I cast rays within the bounding box with a set spacing between each ray. The ray goes from left to right incrementing by 1 pixel.

[image]

Whenever a cast ray gets to a pixel with RGB values of `100, 255, 100` I then know it has entered the shape. I know when it exits the shape if the pixel value **is not** `100, 255, 100`. Thus I know start and end coordinates for each line within my shape and if one ray enters and exits the shape multiple times - this will generate all line segments within that one ray cast.

[image]

For the most part it works but there are issues:

1. It's very slow. Perhaps there is a better way than casting rays? Or perhaps there is a way to optimize the ray logic? Perhaps something more intelligent than just checking for RGB color values?
2. How do I cast rays at a different angle **within** the bounding box? Now it's going left to right, but how would I fill my bounding box with rays cast at any specified angle? i.e.:

[image] [image]

I don't care about holes or curves. The shapes will all be made of straight line segments and won't have any holes inside them.

Edit: made changes to the pixel RGB sampling that improve performance.

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

lineSpacing = 15;

shape = [
  [150,10], // x, y
  [10,300],  
  [150,200],
  [300,300]
];

boundingBox = [
  [Infinity,Infinity],
  [-Infinity,-Infinity]
]

// get bounding box coords
for(var i in shape) {
  if(shape[i][0] < boundingBox[0][0]) boundingBox[0][0] = shape[i][0];  
  if(shape[i][1] < boundingBox[0][1]) boundingBox[0][1] = shape[i][1];   

  if(shape[i][0] > boundingBox[1][0]) boundingBox[1][0] = shape[i][0];  
  if(shape[i][1] > boundingBox[1][1]) boundingBox[1][1] = shape[i][1];   
}

// display bounding box
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,.2)';
ctx.fillRect(boundingBox[0][0], boundingBox[0][1], boundingBox[1][0]-boundingBox[0][0], boundingBox[1][1]-boundingBox[0][1]);

// display shape (boundary)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(shape[0][0], shape[0][1]);

for(var i = 1; i < shape.length; i++) {
  ctx.lineTo(shape[i][0], shape[i][1]);  
}

ctx.closePath();
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(100,255,100,1)';
ctx.fill();

canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;

// loop through the shape in vertical slices
for(var i = boundingBox[0][1]+lineSpacing; i <= boundingBox[1][1]; i += lineSpacing) {

  // send ray from left to right
  for(var j = boundingBox[0][0], start = false; j <= boundingBox[1][0]; j++) {

    x = j, y = i;  
    pixel = y * (canvas.width * 4) + x * 4;    

    // if pixel is within boundary (shape)
    if(canvasData[pixel] == 100 && canvasData[pixel+1] == 255 && canvasData[pixel+2] == 100) {
      // arrived at start of boundary
      if(start === false) {
        start = [x,y]
      }
    } else {
      // arrived at end of boundary
      if(start !== false) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(start[0], start[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);   
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();    

        start = false;
      }
    }

  }
  // show entire cast ray for debugging purposes
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,.2)';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(boundingBox[0][0], i);
  ctx.lineTo(boundingBox[1][0], i);   
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();  
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="350" height="350"></canvas>
```

Comment: Do you just need to draw it or do you really need to know the coordinates? CanvasPattern can do this extremely easily, so does compositing.

Comment: @Kaiido I need the coordinates for paths within the boundary (shape), in fact I don't even need to display the rays, shape, etc. - they're only there to visualize the problem. I'll later be working only with the rays within the shape.

Comment: And do what with these rays? A graphic representation of these won't help? If so, why tag this question canvas?

Comment: I'll be walking through each ray inside a shape and use those coordinates as points to sample data from another data set. In turn that sampled data will be displayed along those vector lines. In essence the ray will change color depending on the audio it sampled. So I need exact coordinates for sample points as well as displaying information and not just a visual representation, and all that will be presented on the same HTML canvas, thus canvas tag ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there would be a way to do all this by compositing, but anyway. So by ypur logic since this will be rendered in a [browser] probably on [windows] [mac-os] or [linux], all these tags should be used? If your question is not about the canvas API, and you refuse solutions based on that, this tag is irrelevant.

Comment: One way to check if a point is on the line of the shape is to:
First create the shape using a new Path2D object. Then you use things like lineTo to make the full shape, finally drawing the shape onto the canvas with context.draw(path2d).
Then, you use context.isPointInStroke(path2D, x, y) to find if the (x,y) point is on the outline of the shape.

Comment: Kaido another use case that I'll be using this is for filling in shapes for plotting, representing tool paths in canvas and exporting those lines in SVG. I don't understand why you're trying to cram raster techniques that will not work for my use cases and arguing that they should OR that I shouldn't be using the canvas tag when in all my use cases these generated lines will be displayed in canvas.

Comment: Just a comment about the case of angles. If you learn how to do this using horizontal lines, then when you select some other angle `a`, then you can rotate the input data of the polygon by an angle of `-a`, then execute the algorithm for horizontal lines, and after you are done, rotate the results by angle of `a`.

Comment: Thanks! That might actually work. I haven't given up on rays at an angle yet though :D But I'll try your suggestion too!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty complex problem that I am trying to simplify as much as possible. Using the line intersection formula we can determin where the ray intersects with the shape at every edge. What we can do is loop through each side of the shape while check every rays intersection. If they intersect we push those coordinates to an array.

I have tried to make this as dynamic as possible. You can pass the shape and change the number of rays and the angle. As for the angle it doesn't take a specific degree (i.e. 45) but rather you change the start and stop y axis. I'm sure if you must have the ability to put in a degree we can do that.

It currently console logs the array of intersecting coordinates but you can output them however you see fit.

The mouse function is just to verify that the number match up. Also be aware I am using `toFixed()` to get rid of lots of decimals but it does convert to a string. If you need an integer you'll have to convert back.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
ctx.fillStyle = "violet";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)

//Shapes
let triangleish = [
  [150,10], // x, y
  [10,300],   
  [150,200],
  [300,300]
]
let star = [ [ 0, 85 ], [ 75, 75 ], [ 100, 10 ], [ 125, 75 ], 
[ 200, 85 ], [ 150, 125 ], [ 160, 190 ], [ 100, 150 ], 
[ 40, 190 ], [ 50, 125 ], [ 0, 85 ] ];

let coords = [];

//Class that draws the shape on canvas
function drawShape(arr) {
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0,255,0)";
   ctx.moveTo(arr[0][0], arr[0][1]);
   for (let i=1;i<arr.length;i++) {
     ctx.lineTo(arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);  
   }
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.closePath();
}
//pass the shape in here to draw it
drawShape(star)

//Class to creat the rays. 
class Rays {
  constructor(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    this.x1 = x1;
    this.y1 = y1;
    this.x2 = x2;
    this.y2 = y2;
    this.w = canvas.width;
    this.h = 1;
  }
  draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.moveTo(this.x1, this.y1)
    ctx.lineTo(this.x2, this.y2)
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

let rays = [];
function createRays(angle) {
  let degrees = angle * (Math.PI/180)
    //I am currently creating an array every 10px on the Y axis
  for (let i=0; i < angle + 45; i++) {
      //The i will be your start and stop Y axis. This is where you can change the angle
    let cx = canvas.width/2 + (angle*2);
    let cy = i * 10;
    let x1 = (cx - 1000 * Math.cos(degrees));
    let y1 =  (cy - 1000 * Math.sin(degrees));
    let x2 = (cx + 1000 * Math.cos(degrees));
    let y2 =  (cy + 1000 * Math.sin(degrees));
    rays.push(new Rays(x1, y1, x2, y2))
  }
}
//enter angle here
createRays(40);

//function to draw the rays after crating them
function drawRays() {
  for (let i=0;i<rays.length; i++) {
    rays[i].draw();
  }
}
drawRays();

//This is where the magic happens. Using the line intersect formula we can determine if the rays intersect with the objects sides
function intersectLines(coord1, coord2, rays) {
    let x1 = coord1[0];
    let x2 = coord2[0];
    let y1 = coord1[1];
    let y2 = coord2[1];
  
    let x3 = rays.x1;
    let x4 = rays.x2;
    let y3 = rays.y1;
    let y4 = rays.y2;
    //All of this comes from Wikipedia on line intersect formulas
    let d = (x1 - x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3 - x4);
    if (d == 0) {
        return
    }
    let t =  ((x1 - x3)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y3)*(x3 - x4)) / d;
    let u =  ((x2 - x1)*(y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1)*(x1 - x3)) / d;
    //if this statement is true then the lines intersect
    if (t > 0 && t < 1 && u > 0) {
        //I have currently set it to fixed but if a string does not work for you you can change it however you want.
        //the first formula is the X coord of the interect the second is the Y
        coords.push([(x1 + t*(x2 - x1)).toFixed(2),(y1 + t*(y2 - y1)).toFixed(2)])
    }
    return
}

//function to call the intersect function by passing in the shapes sides and each ray
function callIntersect(shape) {
  for (let i=0;i<shape.length;i++) { 
    for (let j=0;j<rays.length;j++) {
      if (i < shape.length - 1) {
        intersectLines(shape[i], shape[i+1], rays[j]);
      } else {
        intersectLines(shape[0], shape[shape.length - 1], rays[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
callIntersect(star);

//just to sort them by the Y axis so they they show up as in-and-out
function sortCoords() {
    coords.sort((a, b) => {
        return a[1] - b[1];
    });
}
sortCoords()
console.log(coords)

//This part is not needed only added to verify number matched the mouse posit
let mouse = {
    x: undefined,
    y: undefined
}
let canvasBounds = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    mouse.x = e.x - canvasBounds.left;
    mouse.y = e.y - canvasBounds.top;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    drawCoordinates();
})

function drawCoordinates() {
    ctx.font = '15px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillText('x: '+mouse.x+' y: '+mouse.y, mouse.x, mouse.y)
}

function animate() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.fillStyle = "violet";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)
    for (let i=0;i<rays.length; i++) {
        rays[i].draw();
      }
    drawShape(star)
    drawCoordinates();
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate()
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow, that intersecting formula is pure gold! I managed to reduce the lag by saving RGB values once to an array and getting RGB values per pixel by looking them up which is fast-ish, but not as great as this, amazing!

I've been trying to generate paths at a set angle inside the bounding box, but it's a total fail https://jsfiddle.net/thfva28o/ 

I've been referencing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46765161/ but the spacing between lines is wrong, it gets shorter the greater the angle..

How would I specify an angle with your method?

Comment: It is useful. I just updated to to take an angle in degrees as an argument in the create rays function. Be aware as you increase the angle towards 90 it lines will start to stack do to the x coord. You may want to add a condition that switch the alignment once it reaches a certain degree. Although I think this is the best route for what you want I am interested in using `getImageDate` to do the same thing. I may play around with that.

Comment: We're having the same problem with rays getting spaced differently at different angles, just like in my thrown together code in the comment above. Try setting the angle to 80 or something and you'll see how close the rays are compared to shallower angles like 20 for example. I need to keep the rays spaced apart at a set distance for any angle, don't understand why they get closer together..

Comment: I updated the original question to include the performance update I mentioned. Lines 43, 52 and 55 are where the changes are.

Comment: Vectors! Gaaah, of course the spacing is off. We need to extend a vector out of the path at 90 degrees with a set offset, that way the lines will be spaced evenly.

Comment: Unfortunately I am stuck. I have an almost solution except the when rotating the canvas I don't know how to get the current coordinates of an object before `restore()`. It uses `.getTransform` but I don't understand the matrix use. I have posted another question with the problem. If we can get that answered we should be good. also here a s Codepen useing rays from the center out. It may be useful to you also. https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/ZEeeRPL

Comment: I'll post my own answer shortly as I got it working by mashing your intersect code along with what I made previously, but I have an issue I don't know how to solve

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, but maybe you could do something like this:

1. Generate the points that constitute the borders.
2. Organize them in a convenient structure, e.g. an object with the `y` as key, and an array of `x` as values.

2.1. i.e. each item in the object would constitute all points of all borders in a single `y`.

3. Iterate over the object and generate the segments for each `y`.

3.1. e.g. if the array of `y=12` contains `[ 10, 20, 60, 80 ]` then you would generate two segments: `[ 10, 12 ] --> [ 20, 12 ]` and `[ 60, 12 ] --> [ 80, 12 ]`.

To generate the borders' points (and to answer your second question), you can use the line function `y = a*x + b`.

For example, to draw a line between `[ 10, 30 ]` and `[ 60, 40 ]`, you would:

4. Solve `a` and `b` by substituting `x` and `y` for both points and combining these two formulas (with standard algebra):

```
For point #1: 30 = a*10 + b
For point #2: 40 = a*60 + b

b = 30 - a*10
40 = a*60 + (30 - a*10)
a*60 - a*10 = 40 - 30
50*a = 10
a = 0.2

30 = a*10 + b
30 = 0.2*10 + b
b = 30 - 2
b = 28
```

5. With `a` and `b` at hand, you get the function for your specific line:
   `y = 0.2*x + 28`
6. With that, you can calculate the point of the line for any `y`. So, for example, the `x` of the point right under the first point (`[ 10, 30 ]`) would have a `y` of `31`, and so: `31 = 0.2*x + 28`, and so: `x = 15`. So you get: `[ 15, 31 ]`.

You may need a bit of special handling for:

7. Vertical lines, because the slope is "infinite" and calculating it would cause division by zero.
8. Rounding issues. For some (probably most) pixels you will get real `x` values (i.e. non-integer). You can `Math.round()` them, but it can cause issues, like:

8.1. Diagonal rays may not actually hit a border point even when they go through a border. This will probably require additional handling (like checking points around and not just exactly the pixels the ray lies on).

8.2. The points your algorithm generate may (slightly) differ from the points that appear on the screen when you use libraries or built-in browser functionality to draw the shape (depending on the implementation of their drawing algorithms).

Comment: Interesting approach, but it does break down a bit when dealing with angled lines.. Still have no idea how to generate lines inside the bounding box at set angles though ..

Comment: If you have the angle you can calculate `a` (i.e. the slope, which would be the angle's tangent; you can use `Math.tan()` but note that it expects the angle in radians). `b` would be the offset of the line (the height where it collides with the `y` axis). Once you have `a` and `b` - the rest is as I described above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a mashup of [Justin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67655382/1353395) and code from my proposed question.

One issue was generating rays at a set angle and a set distance from each other. To have rays be equal distances apart at any angle we can use a vector at a 90 degree angle and then place a new center point for the next line.

We can start at the exact midpoint of our boundary and then spread out on either side.

Red line is the center line, green dots are the vector offset points for the next line.

[image]

Next I modified Justin's intersect algorithm to iterate by ray and not side, that way I get interlaced coordinates where `array[index]` is the start point of a segment and `array[index+1]` is the end point.

[image]

And by connecting the lines we get a shape that is filled with lines inside its boundaries at set distances apart

[image]

Issues:

1. I had to inflate the boundary by 1 pixel otherwise certain shapes would fail to generate paths
2. I'd like rays to be some what aligned. It's hard to explain, but here's an example of 6 triangles rotated at 60 degree increments that form a hexagon with their inner lines also offset by 60 degree increments. The top and bottom triangle inner lines do not join those of the outside triangles. This is an issue with the cast rays. Ideally I'd like them to join and be aligned with the outer most edge if that makes sense. Surely there is a better way to cast rays than this...

[image]

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

lineSpacing = 12;
angle = 45;


shapes = [
    [[143.7,134.2], [210.4,18.7], [77.1,18.7]],
    [[143.7,134.2], [77.1,18.7], [10.4,134.2]],
    [[143.7,134.2], [10.4,134.2], [77.1,249.7]],
    [[143.7,134.2], [77.1,249.7], [210.4,249.7]],
    [[143.7,134.2], [210.4,249.7], [277.1,134.2]],
    [[143.7,134.2], [277.1,134.2], [210.4,18.7]]
];

for(var i in shapes) {

    lines = getLineSegments(shapes[i], 90+(-60*i), lineSpacing);

    for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 2) {

        start = lines[i];
        end = lines[i+1];

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
        ctx.moveTo(start[0], start[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(end[0], end[1]);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();
    }   
}

function getLineSegments(shape, angle, lineSpacing) {

    boundingBox = [
        [Infinity,Infinity],
        [-Infinity,-Infinity]
    ]

    // get bounding box coords
    for(var i in shape) {
        if(shape[i][0] < boundingBox[0][0]) boundingBox[0][0] = shape[i][0];    
        if(shape[i][1] < boundingBox[0][1]) boundingBox[0][1] = shape[i][1];   

        if(shape[i][0] > boundingBox[1][0]) boundingBox[1][0] = shape[i][0];    
        if(shape[i][1] > boundingBox[1][1]) boundingBox[1][1] = shape[i][1];   
    }

    boundingBox[0][0] -= 1, boundingBox[0][1] -= 1;
    boundingBox[1][0] += 1, boundingBox[1][1] += 1;

    // display shape (boundary)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(shape[0][0], shape[0][1]);

    for(var i = 1; i < shape.length; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(shape[i][0], shape[i][1]);  
    }

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(100,255,100,1)';
    ctx.fill();

    boundingMidX = ((boundingBox[0][0]+boundingBox[1][0]) / 2);
    boundingMidY = ((boundingBox[0][1]+boundingBox[1][1]) / 2);

    rayPaths = [];

    path = getPathCoords(boundingBox, 0, 0, angle);
    rayPaths.push(path);

    /*ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.moveTo(path[0][0], path[0][1]);
    ctx.lineTo(path[1][0], path[1][1]);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();*/

    getPaths:
    for(var i = 0, lastPaths = [path, path]; true; i++) {

        for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

            pathMidX = (lastPaths[j][0][0] + lastPaths[j][1][0]) / 2;
            pathMidY = (lastPaths[j][0][1] + lastPaths[j][1][1]) / 2;

            pathVectorX = lastPaths[j][1][1] - lastPaths[j][0][1];
            pathVectorY = lastPaths[j][1][0] - lastPaths[j][0][0];

            pathLength = Math.sqrt(pathVectorX * pathVectorX + pathVectorY * pathVectorY);

            pathOffsetPointX = pathMidX + ((j % 2 === 0 ? pathVectorX : -pathVectorX) / pathLength * lineSpacing);
            pathOffsetPointY = pathMidY + ((j % 2 === 0 ? -pathVectorY : pathVectorY) / pathLength * lineSpacing);      

            offsetX = pathOffsetPointX-boundingMidX;
            offsetY = pathOffsetPointY-boundingMidY;

            path = getPathCoords(boundingBox, offsetX, offsetY, angle);

            if(
                path[0][0] < boundingBox[0][0] ||
                path[1][0] > boundingBox[1][0] ||
                path[0][0] > boundingBox[1][0] ||
                path[1][0] < boundingBox[0][0] 
            ) break getPaths;

            /*ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
            ctx.fillRect(pathOffsetPointX-2.5, pathOffsetPointY-2.5, 5, 5); 

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.moveTo(path[0][0], path[0][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(path[1][0], path[1][1]);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();*/
            rayPaths.push(path);
            lastPaths[j] = path;

        }

    }

    coords = [];
  
    function intersectLines(coord1, coord2, rays) {
        x1 = coord1[0], x2 = coord2[0];
        y1 = coord1[1],  y2 = coord2[1];

        x3 = rays[0][0], x4 = rays[1][0];
        y3 = rays[0][1], y4 = rays[1][1];

        d = (x1 - x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3 - x4);
        if (d == 0) return;
    
        t =  ((x1 - x3)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y3)*(x3 - x4)) / d;
        u =  ((x2 - x1)*(y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1)*(x1 - x3)) / d;
        if (t > 0 && t < 1 && u > 0) {
            coords.push([(x1 + t*(x2 - x1)).toFixed(2),(y1 + t*(y2 - y1)).toFixed(2)])
        }
        return;
    }

    function callIntersect(shape) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rayPaths.length; i++) { 
            for (var j = 0; j< shape.length; j++) {
                if (j < shape.length - 1) {
                    intersectLines(shape[j], shape[j+1], rayPaths[i]);
                } else {
                    intersectLines(shape[0], shape[shape.length - 1], rayPaths[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    callIntersect(shape);
    
    return coords;

}

function getPathCoords(boundingBox, offsetX, offsetY, angle) {

    coords = [];

    // add decimal places otherwise can lead to Infinity, subtract 90 so 0 degrees is at the top
    angle = angle + 0.0000000000001 - 90;

    boundingBoxWidth = boundingBox[1][0] - boundingBox[0][0];
    boundingBoxHeight = boundingBox[1][1] - boundingBox[0][1];

    boundingMidX = ((boundingBox[0][0]+boundingBox[1][0]) / 2);
    boundingMidY = ((boundingBox[0][1]+boundingBox[1][1]) / 2);

    x = boundingMidX + offsetX, y = boundingMidY + offsetY;

    dx = Math.cos(Math.PI * angle / 180);
    dy = Math.sin(Math.PI * angle / 180);

    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        bx = (dx > 0) ? boundingBoxWidth+boundingBox[0][0] : boundingBox[0][0];
        by = (dy > 0) ? boundingBoxHeight+boundingBox[0][1] : boundingBox[0][1];        

        if(dx == 0) ix = x, iy = by;        
        if(dy == 0) iy = y, ix = bx;        

        tx = (bx - x) / dx;
        ty = (by - y) / dy;

        if(tx <= ty) {
            ix = bx, iy = y + tx * dy;
        } else {
            iy = by, ix = x + ty * dx;
        }

        coords.push([ix, iy]);  
        
        dx = -dx;   
        dy = -dy;   
    }

    return coords;

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

```js
canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

lineSpacing = 10;
angle = 45;

shape = [
    [200,10], // x, y
    [10,300],  
    [200,200],
    [400,300]
];

lines = getLineSegments(shape, angle, lineSpacing);

for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 2) {

    start = lines[i];
    end = lines[i+1];

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,1)';
    ctx.moveTo(start[0], start[1]);
    ctx.lineTo(end[0], end[1]);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function getLineSegments(shape, angle, lineSpacing) {

    boundingBox = [
        [Infinity,Infinity],
        [-Infinity,-Infinity]
    ]

    // get bounding box coords
    for(var i in shape) {
        if(shape[i][0] < boundingBox[0][0]) boundingBox[0][0] = shape[i][0];    
        if(shape[i][1] < boundingBox[0][1]) boundingBox[0][1] = shape[i][1];   

        if(shape[i][0] > boundingBox[1][0]) boundingBox[1][0] = shape[i][0];    
        if(shape[i][1] > boundingBox[1][1]) boundingBox[1][1] = shape[i][1];   
    }

    boundingBox[0][0] -= 1, boundingBox[0][1] -= 1;
    boundingBox[1][0] += 1, boundingBox[1][1] += 1;

    // display bounding box
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,.2)';
    ctx.fillRect(boundingBox[0][0], boundingBox[0][1], boundingBox[1][0]-boundingBox[0][0], boundingBox[1][1]-boundingBox[0][1]);   

    // display shape (boundary)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(shape[0][0], shape[0][1]);

    for(var i = 1; i < shape.length; i++) {
      ctx.lineTo(shape[i][0], shape[i][1]);  
    }

    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(100,255,100,1)';
    ctx.fill();

    boundingMidX = ((boundingBox[0][0]+boundingBox[1][0]) / 2);
    boundingMidY = ((boundingBox[0][1]+boundingBox[1][1]) / 2);

    rayPaths = [];

    path = getPathCoords(boundingBox, 0, 0, angle);
    rayPaths.push(path);

    /*ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.moveTo(path[0][0], path[0][1]);
    ctx.lineTo(path[1][0], path[1][1]);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();*/

    getPaths:
    for(var i = 0, lastPaths = [path, path]; true; i++) {

        for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

            pathMidX = (lastPaths[j][0][0] + lastPaths[j][1][0]) / 2;
            pathMidY = (lastPaths[j][0][1] + lastPaths[j][1][1]) / 2;

            pathVectorX = lastPaths[j][1][1] - lastPaths[j][0][1];
            pathVectorY = lastPaths[j][1][0] - lastPaths[j][0][0];

            pathLength = Math.sqrt(pathVectorX * pathVectorX + pathVectorY * pathVectorY);

            pathOffsetPointX = pathMidX + ((j % 2 === 0 ? pathVectorX : -pathVectorX) / pathLength * lineSpacing);
            pathOffsetPointY = pathMidY + ((j % 2 === 0 ? -pathVectorY : pathVectorY) / pathLength * lineSpacing);      

            offsetX = pathOffsetPointX-boundingMidX;
            offsetY = pathOffsetPointY-boundingMidY;

            path = getPathCoords(boundingBox, offsetX, offsetY, angle);

            if(
                path[0][0] < boundingBox[0][0] ||
                path[1][0] > boundingBox[1][0] ||
                path[0][0] > boundingBox[1][0] ||
                path[1][0] < boundingBox[0][0] 
            ) break getPaths;

            /*ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
            ctx.fillRect(pathOffsetPointX-2.5, pathOffsetPointY-2.5, 5, 5); 

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.lineWidth = 1;
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.moveTo(path[0][0], path[0][1]);
            ctx.lineTo(path[1][0], path[1][1]);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();*/
            rayPaths.push(path);
            lastPaths[j] = path;

        }

    }

    coords = [];
  
    function intersectLines(coord1, coord2, rays) {
        x1 = coord1[0], x2 = coord2[0];
        y1 = coord1[1],  y2 = coord2[1];

        x3 = rays[0][0], x4 = rays[1][0];
        y3 = rays[0][1], y4 = rays[1][1];

        d = (x1 - x2)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y2)*(x3 - x4);
        if (d == 0) return;
    
        t =  ((x1 - x3)*(y3 - y4) - (y1 - y3)*(x3 - x4)) / d;
        u =  ((x2 - x1)*(y1 - y3) - (y2 - y1)*(x1 - x3)) / d;
        if (t > 0 && t < 1 && u > 0) {
            coords.push([(x1 + t*(x2 - x1)).toFixed(2),(y1 + t*(y2 - y1)).toFixed(2)])
        }
        return;
    }

    function callIntersect(shape) {
        for (var i = 0; i < rayPaths.length; i++) { 
            for (var j = 0; j< shape.length; j++) {
                if (j < shape.length - 1) {
                    intersectLines(shape[j], shape[j+1], rayPaths[i]);
                } else {
                    intersectLines(shape[0], shape[shape.length - 1], rayPaths[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    callIntersect(shape);
    
    return coords;

}

function getPathCoords(boundingBox, offsetX, offsetY, angle) {

    coords = [];

    // add decimal places otherwise can lead to Infinity, subtract 90 so 0 degrees is at the top
    angle = angle + 0.0000000000001 - 90;

    boundingBoxWidth = boundingBox[1][0] - boundingBox[0][0];
    boundingBoxHeight = boundingBox[1][1] - boundingBox[0][1];

    boundingMidX = ((boundingBox[0][0]+boundingBox[1][0]) / 2);
    boundingMidY = ((boundingBox[0][1]+boundingBox[1][1]) / 2);

    x = boundingMidX + offsetX, y = boundingMidY + offsetY;

    dx = Math.cos(Math.PI * angle / 180);
    dy = Math.sin(Math.PI * angle / 180);

    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        bx = (dx > 0) ? boundingBoxWidth+boundingBox[0][0] : boundingBox[0][0];
        by = (dy > 0) ? boundingBoxHeight+boundingBox[0][1] : boundingBox[0][1];        

        if(dx == 0) ix = x, iy = by;        
        if(dy == 0) iy = y, ix = bx;        

        tx = (bx - x) / dx;
        ty = (by - y) / dy;

        if(tx <= ty) {
            ix = bx, iy = y + tx * dy;
        } else {
            iy = by, ix = x + ty * dx;
        }

        coords.push([ix, iy]);  
        
        dx = -dx;   
        dy = -dy;   
    }

    return coords;

}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```